# Синоним к Художественное открытие

Tags: лексика, стилистика, синонимы

Можно ли подобрать синоним к понятию "художественное открытие"?

Comment: А что за контекст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Новое слово в искусстве" или "новое слово в литературе" (в зависимости от того, в какой области "художественного" это открытие было сделано).

Comment: Как такого контекста нет. Просто хотел узнать. Спасибо!